# Why I got None after modify the list in the function?

Tags: python, list, variables, global-variables

I wrote a dfs function and return path for all possible from start to destination point.
However, I notice that I get the correct paths in the function, but I didn't get it out of the functions.

```
res = []
Solution s:
    def find all_path(graph:list(list)):
        def dfs(curNode, path: list)->list[list]:
            if curNode == target:
                #Correct one:
                #res.append(list(path))
                #Wrong one:
                res.append(path)
        
                return 
            #all other code without modify the list of res
        path = [start_point]
        dfs(start_point, path)
        return res
```

what's the reason I have to write `res.append(list(path))`?   I remember list A.append(list.B) will get A[ [B] ] format. So, it should be ok.

Tried: Search the website and try to check global veriable, but I did like this in before all the time. Only this time, I didn't get the correct value in outside.

expectation: I would like to know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Wrong one:
res.append(path)
#Appends a reference to the path list to res.
```

If you later modify the path list, the changes will be reflected in the lists inside res because they are references to the same list.

```
#Correct one:
res.append(list(path))
#Creates a new list with the same elements
```

list(path) creates a new list with the same elements as path, so even if you modify path later, the lists inside res remain unchanged.